# Таймаут остановки Win-service

Tags: c#, windows-7

Для теста мне нужен сервис который будет останавливаться 10-15 мин.

Я создал свой простейший Win-сервис:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace LongService
{   
    public class LongService : ServiceBase
    {
        private EventLog eventLog1;
        public const string MyServiceName = "LongService";
        public const string logName = "LongServiceLog";

        public LongService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ServiceName = MyServiceName;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            AddLog("start");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            AddLog("stop");
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit(600000);

        }

        public void AddLog(string log)
        {
          try
          {
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(MyServiceName))
            {
              EventLog.CreateEventSource(MyServiceName, logName);
            }

            eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            eventLog1.Source = MyServiceName;
            eventLog1.Log = logName;            
            eventLog1.WriteEntry(log);
          }
          catch{}
        }


    }
}
```

Вопрос: как мне правильно отложить(задержать) остановку сервиса с таймаутом в самом сервисе

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit(600000);
```

или как увеличить таймаут в винде в реестре. Т.к. Ожидание остановки сервиса в винде не более 2 мин. через 2 мин винда выкидывает ошибку

> 1053. служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну и пусть выкидывает. Сервису послали команду остановиться, сервис не остановился за время ожидания. Windows выдала предупреждение и забыла об этом сервисе. Пройдут Ваши 10-15 минут и сервис штатно остановится

При останове сервис проходит через статусы `SERVICE_RUNNING` - `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` - `SERVICE_STOPPED`. PENDING статусы могут висеть сколь угодно долго. Особенности начинаются при работе с зависимыми сервисами. Например, если `SERVICE_START_PENDING` висит дольше тех же 2 минут, то сервисы, зависимые от этого, не запускаются

Comment: Любопытно, я никогда не задумывался о том, что происходит, если сервис не хочет останавливаться. Наверное, если бы меня вдруг спросили - я бы сказал "да просто прибиваются зависшие процессы по таймауту- вот и всё". Но вот вспоминая какой-нибудь зависший w3wp - да, если не получалось штатно остановить - то приходилось через диспетчер задач убивать.

Comment: @AK Нет. Смотри расширенный ответ

Comment: Спасибо работает. 
действительно выдает SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, а большего мне и нужно.

Comment: @Alex Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как верный

Comment: Да, после после проведения тестов оказалось, что Ваш ответ удовлетворяет моим потребностям. При-много благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

[Пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18380060/5752652), что ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime может помочь.

```
ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
```

Добавить по вкусу в OnStop/OnStart/OnContinue/OnPause.

Я рецепт не проверял, возможно, что есть настройки в ОС, которые ограничивают добавочное время.

Да, [вот](https://serverfault.com/a/622435/362960): ServicesPipeTimeout в HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control

PS И я не знаю, что вы тестите, но в той же теме совершенно правильно говорится, что нужно при старте/остановке сервиса долгие вещи выносить в отдельный поток.

Comment: Спасибо работает. 
ключ в реестре можно изменить со 120000 на необходимое значение. 
код не тестил, но обязательно это сделаю и соберу все в один большой ответ. и напишу
`
ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
`